Overlapping carousel images issue
I have a working carousel: images enter from the right side of the screen when clicking on one of the buttons at the bottom, they stay on the screen and move to the left when clicking on another button.
The user can click on any button without a defined order and the images always enter from the right.
The problem is when clicking on a previous adjacent button (try A and B at the code example) , since the image "has not had time to return to its original position", it enters from the left.
Is there a solution?


const imageContainer = document.getElementById("image-container");
const imageSlides = imageContainer.querySelectorAll(".image-slide");
let currentSlideIndex = 0;

function showImage(slideIndex) {
  imageSlides.forEach(slide => { 
    slide.classList.remove("active"); 
    slide.classList.remove("exit");
  });

  imageSlides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");

  if (currentSlideIndex > 0) { 
    imageSlides[currentSlideIndex - 1].classList.add("exit");
  }

  currentSlideIndex = slideIndex;
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".gota");

buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => showImage(index + 1));

});
* {
  font-family           : helvetica;
  text-align            : center;
  font-size             : 14px;
  font-weight           : bold;
  }
.container {
  width                 : 100vw;
  height                : 100vh;
  }
.buttons {
  display               : grid;
  width                 : 100%;
  height                : 100%;
  grid-template-columns : repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, max-content));
  gap                   : 30px;
  grid-auto-flow        : row;
  justify-items         : center;
  align-items           : center;
  justify-content       : center;
  }
.gota {
  top                   : -80px;
  width                 : 25px;
  height                : 20px;
  border-radius         : 25%;
  background-color      : red;
  position              : relative;
  margin                : 10px auto;
  cursor                : pointer;
  padding-top           : 4px;
  color                 : #fff;
  }
#image-container {
  position              : relative;
  width                 : 100%;
  height                : 200px;
  overflow              : hidden;
  top                   : 20%;
  }
.image-slide {
  content               : '';
  position              : absolute;
  top                   : 0;
  left                  : 100%;
  width                 : 100%;
  height                : 100%;
  object-fit            : cover;
  transition            : left 1s ease-in-out;
  z-index               : 0;
}
#image1 { background-color: blue;      }
#image2 { background-color: gray;      }
#image3 { background-color: brown;     }
#image4 { background-color: orange;    }
#image5 { background-color: purple;    }
#image6 { background-color: darkgreen; }

.image-slide.active {
  left    : 0;
  z-index : 20;
  }
.image-slide.exit {
  left    : -100%;
  z-index : 20;
  }
<div class="container">

  <div id="image-container">
    <img src="#" class="image-slide" id="image1">
    <img src="#" class="image-slide" id="image2">
    <img src="#" class="image-slide" id="image3">
    <img src="#" class="image-slide" id="image4">
    <img src="#" class="image-slide" id="image5">
    <img src="#" class="image-slide" id="image6">
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="gota"></div>
    <div class="gota"></div>
    <div class="gota">A</div>
    <div class="gota">B</div>
    <div class="gota"></div>
    <div class="gota"></div>
  </div>

  <div>




you should use the promise system in JavaScript for this kind of problem -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises
